# XP taskbar not horizontal far right

Tags: windows, windows-xp

XP taskbar far right icons line up vertically.
How do I get them to be horizontal?
Anyone with any suggestions would be a help

Comment: are you talking about the system tray icons near the clock? or the taskbar itself is vertical on the right?

Comment: near the clock---icons line up vertically but need to be horizontal

Comment: Thank you for comments, but I've put enough into this old computer and person I'm trying to help can take it or leave it(go buy another computer and upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the task bar and remove the check mark next to "lock taskbar" if there is one there. At this point, you should have a delimiter bar, a series of vertical dots adjacent to the icons. You should be able to drag that bar to expand the region which encompasses the icons.

Occasionally, you may discover that you can't get the delimiter bar to move. It may be necessary to turn off and back on other features on the task bar context menu (right-click) to get the system to accept your objective.

Sometimes the quick launch feature interferes with the movement and also has to be repositioned. It's been a hit-or-miss task for me in the past.